# org-mode markdown broken

Tags: org-mode, markdown

I install (latest) org-mode on emacs 25.1 from
http://orgmode.org/elpa/ like this

```
(use-package org
  :ensure org-plus-contrib
  :defer t)

(require 'ox-md)
```

If I try to export the draft of my book (this is just used as a ready example, any `org-mode` file I create suffers the same problem)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fommil/fp-scala-mortals/master/manuscript/book.org

using `C-c C-e` and select `m m` (Markdown), I get this error:

```
  Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp #("2017" 0 4 
(:parent (#1))))
    org-element-set-contents(#("2017" 0 4 (:parent (#0))))
    apply(org-element-set-contents #("2017" 0 4 (:parent (#0))) nil)
```

If I revert back to the version of `ox-md` that comes with Emacs 25.1, the file is exported ok.

Is this a bug or have I done something dumb?

Comment: I use close to bleeding-edge org-mode: Org mode version 9.0.5 (release_9.0.5-444-g998576 @ /home/nick/elisp/org-mode/lisp/) and cloe to bleeding-edge emacs:  GNU Emacs 26.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.20.10) of 2017-04-14. I was able to export your book to markdown with no problems.

Comment: I guess I should wait for the next releases then. Still not working for me.